# How to calculate the distance in meters between a geographic point and a given polygon?

Tags: java, gis, geospatial, geotools

First of all, I'm new to GIS, so pardon any mistakes. I need to discover the distance between a latitude and longitude point and a latitude/longitude polygon (regular or not). Precisely, I need to discover the minimal distance from a given point to a point in the polygon's boundary, as illustrated below. In the example, the closer distance from point `p` to the polygon is `d`. Note: I don't need the point, just the minimum distance.

[image: Problem Illustration]

After some reading, I've come up with the following minimum working example using the GeoTools API. However, I think I'm messing up in the output. Can anyone enlight me on how to get the minimum distance between a point and polygon in mteres?

MWE.java:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;

public class MWE {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

        Coordinate[] c = new Coordinate[5];
        c[0] = new Coordinate(-49.242986, -16.662430);
        c[1] = new Coordinate(-49.241999, -16.664465);
        c[2] = new Coordinate(-49.239146, -16.663828);
        c[3] = new Coordinate(-49.239832, -16.661443);
        c[4] = new Coordinate(-49.242986, -16.662430);

        Geometry geo = gf.createPolygon(c);

        Point p = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(-49.246870, -16.665493));

        double distance = geo.distance(p);

        System.out.println("Distance: " + distance);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you working with a regular polygon ?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by distance between point and polygon.  Do you mean from the polygon centroid or from the closest point on the boundary?

Comment: Any polygon. It is to one of the polygons points. 
I tried to clarify in the question.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to find minimum of the distances between a point and 5 points ? Doesn't that mean that you just need to know how to find distance between two lat/long points ?

Comment: @11thdimension Actually is any point in the polygon boundary. I'll try to add an image that explain this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So what you are doing is correct, but it will return distance in geodetic units (degrees of arc) rather than metres.  You have two options:

1. transform the point and the polygon geometries to a planar reference system http://docs.geotools.org/latest/tutorials/geometry/geometrycrs.html
2. Use the GeodeticCalculator http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/calculator.html

To use the GeodeticCalculator you will need to determine the closest point on the polygon boundary to your point. e.g. `DistanceOp.closestPoints(geo, p)[0]`

```
// adapted from http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/calculator.html
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
GeodeticCalculator gc = new GeodeticCalculator(crs);
gc.setStartingPosition( JTS.toDirectPosition(  DistanceOp.closestPoints(geo, p)[0], crs ) );
gc.setDestinationPosition( JTS.toDirectPosition( p, crs ) );

double distance = gc.getOrthodromicDistance();
```

Comment: major key    still can't understand how this answer only has 9 upvotes with 7k views. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of creating GeodeticCalculator and setting positions, you can use JTS.orthodromicDistance(), it does pretty much the same but you save some space